# Finding redundant variables

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I have data of several variables (all numeric or continuous) on different subjects. I want to find out if some of these variables are highly correlated so that not all need to be determined. This will reduce the number of variables that may need to be determined in future. How can I check for redundant variables- principal component analysis or factor analysis or some other method?

Another aspect is that variables were determined multiple times in some subjects. Hence the number of rows are about 1.5 times the number of subjects. How can I correct for this in my analysis? Thanks for your help.